# eigenvalue and eigenvector question

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

i got stuck in this question of my practice lab. Please give me some hint of how to achieve that question. thank you very much

'Suppose the matrix $A$ has eigenvectors $v$ with corresponding eigenvalues . Show that $v$ is an eigenvector of $A^n$. What is its corresponding eigenvalue?'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $v$ is an eigenvector of $A$, then
$$Av=\lambda v$$
Pre-multiply both sides by matrix $A$
$$A^2v=\lambda Av=\lambda^2v$$
Pre-multiply again by $A$
$$A^3v=\lambda^2Av=\lambda^3v$$
Can you see the pattern?

Comment: yes, thank you very much. ;) you are legend

Comment: You are most welcome.